# Book from the golden age about insect-like aliens pretending to be humans

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, books, novel

I read a sci-fi book a long time ago and really enjoyed it, but for for the life of me, I can't remember its title or author and only remember a few details (really few).

I'm almost certain it was from the golden age or shortly after, maybe from the '50s or '60s.

Its narrative takes place on a planet not completely inhabited I think, where the protagonist finds out about a species of parasites (insect-like, I think, with a larval stage) that evolved to completely replicate the external appearance of a human being after said larval stage in order to live among them and if I remember correctly they are also able to reproduce with a human being. Before finding this out, the protagonist actually falls in love with one of them.

Can't really remember anything else or find any other information online (and I've tried everywhere with lots of different combinations of relevant keywords).

Oh and maybe it was a short story and I'm confusing things.

Really appreciate if someone could shed some light over this.

Comment: Is it also in the plot that the insect thing human form is attracted to women in cars because they are surrounded by a type of "exoskeleton"?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

From very vague memories, it sounds like [The Lovers](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1162042.The_Lovers) by [Philip José Farmer,](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philip_Jos%C3%A9_Farmer).

It also featured "The Sturch", or *State Church*.

Comment: Not sure how vague your memory is, but I would say this is "The Lovers" for sure. Claimed to be the first book with sex between a human and an alien.

Comment: Great, that's exactly it. After all these years, I really thought I was never gonna be able to read it again. Thanks!

Comment: @Zane - it would be over 30 years since I read it, so pretty vague.

Comment: @Eduardo: I think I know how it feels - let's hope you're not disappointed when you read it again. I liked it a lot, and there are many good books by P.J.Farmer.

Comment: @Zane - feel free to expand my answer with any more (non-spoiler) details, to assist others searching. I have made it a wiki

Answer (score 3):

That might perhaps be [*The Pollinators of Eden*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Pollinators_of_Eden) by John Boyd, published in 1969. Although the aliens are plants, not insects.